# Difference between tomcat and resin?

Tags: java, tomcat, resin

I like to know what are the differences between Tomcat container and Resin container

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) is a stand alone web server supporting the J2EE web technologies (eg. Servlets, JSP) and [Resin is a full blown J2EE Application server](http://www.caucho.com/) which includes a web server plus the rest of the J2EE family of technologies (eg. EJB). Tomcat is always free to use for any purpose. Resin is free only for open source or hobby use. Commercial use of Resin is not free. One interesting feature of Resin is the ability to run PHP applications under the JVM through [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/).

Comment: Currently, and since Resin 3, the Resin Open Source edition is licensed under GPL.

Comment: Note: it is not really full blown J2EE. Resin supports the Java EE 6 web profile. So its more like a Tomcat with Spring light.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look [here](http://www.indicthreads.com/1712/apache-tomcat-server-alternatives-jetty-and-resin/) and [here](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/jetty_vs_tomcat_vs_resin)

**Resin**'s high-performance application server features load balancing for increased reliability. Resin encourages separation of content from style with its fast XML and XSL support.
**Resin** is available in two versions, Professional and Open Source. Professional has features commonly needed in a production environment while the Open Source version is said to be suitable for hobbyists and low traffic websites.

**Apache Tomcat** is an *open source* software implementation of the Java Servlet and JavaServer Pages technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Resin server is performance side very high and cost also high whether compare than tomcat server.